# Change value of all objects from query. [parse.com]

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Current code:

```
             var query2 = PFQuery(className: "Post")
                            query2.whereKey("alias", equalTo: self.currentname)


                            query2.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objectos, NSError) -> Void in

                                println(objects.count)
                                if objectos.count != 0 {


                                    for objecto in objectos {

                                    }

                        })
```

I want to change the value of a column in objecto for all objectos. I tried:

```
objecto["alias"]! = self.usernametextfield.text as AnyObject
```

But it doesn't work. So to clarify, I am querying Post, to find all objects where alias is equal to self.currentname. I want to change a string column of all objects found to self.usernametextfield.text.

Comment: what doesn't work? what error do you get in the code or when you save (you are saving, right)

Comment: im getting: Cannot assign a value of type 'anyobject' to a value of type anyobject?

Comment: the issue is that i want to change an array of objects. i know how to change a single object but not an array

Comment: You have a loop so you have single objects to change